# Setting bitmap though setImageBitmap() results only in gifs being visible in view

Tags: android, image, bitmap, jpeg, gif

So my issue is exactly as the title states. I am downloading many different images and scaling them then setting them to a view. My issue is it seems that only `.gif` images are visible in the views that are created and the views that should contain `.jpg` images are almost blank. I say almost because there seems to be a strange tiny black dot on each `.jpg` view of different shapes, and by tiny I mean the size of a period, so those might be the images but reduced in size too much. Any help... p.s Though outputs I am sure the images are going though my bitmap and makeing it to the setImageBitmap().

My bitmap creating method:

```
    @Override   
 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {

    String url1 = url[0];
    InputStream s = null;
    try {
        s = (new URL(url1)).openStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    final BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(s, 32*1024);

        try {
            final Options decodeBitmapOptions = new Options();
            // For further memory savings, you may want to consider using this option
            // decodeBitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565; // Uses 2-bytes instead of default 4 per pixel

            if( parent.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels >0) {
                final Options decodeBoundsOptions = new Options();
                decodeBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                is.mark(32*1024); // 32k is probably overkill, but 8k is insufficient for some jpgs
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,decodeBoundsOptions);
                is.reset();
                final int originalWidth = decodeBoundsOptions.outWidth;
                final int originalHeight = decodeBoundsOptions.outHeight;
                Debug.out("Inbound image preview for : "+url1);
                Debug.out(originalWidth);
                Debug.out(originalHeight);
                // inSampleSize prefers multiples of 2, but we prefer to prioritize memory savings
                decodeBitmapOptions.inSampleSize= Math.max(1,Math.min(originalWidth / 2, originalHeight / 2));
            }

            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,decodeBitmapOptions);
        } catch( IOException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // this shouldn't happen
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch( IOException ignored ) {}
        }


    }
```

Also here is where I set my new image after download :

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap map) {
 //image is a object of type ImageView that has already been added to to the grand scheme of things
     image.setImageBitmap(map);
 }
```

Do I need to update the view or something? If so why do my gifs load fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue turned out to be with my scaling, particularly this line `decodeBitmapOptions.inSampleSize= Math.max(1,Math.min(originalWidth / 2, originalHeight / 2));`